# Let u be an algebraic element of K whose minimal polynomial in F[x] has prime degree. If E is a field such that F<E<F(u), show that E = F or E=F(u)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't know how to even begin this problem, let alone do anything else with it. I would appreciate any help

Comment: I would recommend reading up on the Tower Law and how it applies to field extensions.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't remember that I had closing superpowers via a gold badge. Anyway, the linked question is essentially equivalent. Another post of this question on math.SE is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/642204/264

Answer (score 1):

You should note that $[\Bbb F(u):\Bbb F] = [\Bbb F(u):\Bbb E][\Bbb E:\Bbb F]$.  If the right-hand side is prime, there are only two possible factorizations.